# TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: image-processing, pytorch, mnist, data-augmentation

whenever I try run this code, I receive a

> ```
> TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable.
> ```

How could I fix this?

```
train_data = datasets.MNIST(root='D:\medical_imaging_radiation_therapy\medimg_udemy',
                           train=True, download=True, transform=True )

train_data[0]
```

i sucessfully downloaded MNIST dataset, however, when calling image indexed 0, this error message appears

Answer (score 0):

Please read the doc for [`torchvision.datasets.MNIST`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.datasets.MNIST.html):

> **transform** (callable, optional) – A function/transform that takes in an PIL image and returns a transformed version. E.g, transforms.RandomCrop

The argument `transform` needs to specify the augmentations you want, and it should be a `callable` object. You set `transforms=True`, which is not callable.

try something like:

```py
train_data = datasets.MNIST(root='D:\medical_imaging_radiation_therapy\medimg_udemy',
                           train=True, download=True, transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor())
```